# Why Angular2 routerLinkActive sets active class to multiple links?

Tags: angular, routerlinkactive

I'm trying to implement routerLinkActive to my app but i'm facing the issue that it's sets class active to multiple links. Here's how i'm doing it

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/contact']" >Contact Us</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Here it's how it looks

[image]
Here it's how it look in dev-tools
[image]
And my address bar

[image]

### Am i missing something because i'm doing as explained in [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#router-link-active).

Comment: Can you post your routing configuration as well.

Comment: I think it should be `routerLinkActive="active"` and not `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Try to set `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` to HTML as below :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"><a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/contact']" >Contact Us</a></li>  
</ul>
```

### How does it work ?##

RouterLinkActive does chunk the current route and try to match it's parts with the RouterLinks you've provided. With that in mind, route `/` will be matched anywhere as it's the very parent for all the other routes (like `/about`, `/contact`, etc. as it consist of `/` + `route-path`). To simplify, it's not a bug, it's sometimes a needed functionality in your application to match multiple routes. To prevent that, you can specify the `routerLinkActiveOptions` to match exactly the route you're on. That means it's not going to match parent routes but will only try to find the routerLink provided for this exact route.

Comment: it works because for 1st link url will be "localhost:8080/" and for 2nd link URL is "localhost:8080/about" and if for 1st link if you do not add `routerLinkActiveOptions` then when you visit `localhost:8080/about` page then also it will match starting url "localhost:8080/" and because of it, it sets active class on first link. you have to set `routerLinkActiveOptions` for those URL only for which you want the url matches the link exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import `RouterModule` in `app.module.ts` to make it work.
`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` is also needed to focus only the true route.
Hope this will help some.