# Angular: how to route -parameters from same component?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Issue: Whenever I click into one link it selects both. But it shows individual links correctly.

[image]

I thing when ever I click on link, It didn't refresh the whole route.

My Code: 1. Angular route:

```
{ path: 'gantt/:id', component: GanttWorkItemsComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.WorkItems' }},
{ path: 'gantt', component: GanttWorkItemsComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.WorkItems' } },
```

2.Component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class Gcomponent extens appComponent implements OnInit{

constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _http: Http,
    private _workItemsServiceProxy: WorkItemsServiceProxy,
    private params: ActivatedRoute) {

    super(injector);
    var paramId = params.snapshot.params["id"];

    if (paramId) {
        this.initiativeFilter = paramId;
        this.nameFilter = 'strategy.id=' + this.initiativeFilter;

    }
    } 

  ngOnit(){}
```

}

Comment: Just curious, if you change the order of the routes so that `path: 'gantt'` comes before the `gantt/:id` one, does it change anything?

Answer (score 1):

you should subscribe to this.params.params, so your component will be updated on every route param change

```
constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _http: Http,
    private _workItemsServiceProxy: WorkItemsServiceProxy,
    private params: ActivatedRoute
) {
    super(injector);

    this.params.params.subscribe(() => {
        var paramId = params.snapshot.params["id"];
        if (paramId) {
            this.initiativeFilter = paramId;
            this.nameFilter = 'strategy.id=' + this.initiativeFilter;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately!! Its not working. Should I replace the inner code with this? params.onIdChange = (id) => { this.nameFilter = id ? 'strategy.id=' + id : ''; this.getWorkItems();}

Comment: it's should work, you should put in subscribe() code which will update your component, I can help you more if you will show your component code, try to add in subscribe() init methods and property initial value assigning

Comment: Definitely! I didn't understand one thing. Every time I click at Long list it only select the individual row. But whenever I click on tytufy.. It selcts both .

Comment: maybe smth., wrong in your template, please can you add it too

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up your problematic link DOM elements with exact matching option

`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`

Possible related issue:

[Why Angular2 routerLinkActive sets active class to multiple links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181539/why-angular2-routerlinkactive-sets-active-class-to-multiple-links)