# Angular routerLinkActive with nested routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem. On my page, I have route `/productsList`. And I have `list-group` :

```
<div class="sticky-top">

  <ul class="list-group">
    <a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  [routerLink]="['/productsList']"   routerLinkActive="active"  > sad</a>

    <a *ngFor="let products of categoryProduc; let i = index"  [routerLink]="[products.name]"  routerLinkActive="active"   class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      {{ products.name }}
    </a>
  </ul>

</div>
```

When I click on the some Item of list, route is changed example: `/productsList/product` and item is selected, but my :

```
<a  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"  [routerLink]="['/productsList']"   routerLinkActive="active"  > sad</a>
```

Is always  selected because I always have `/productsList`, I want when I have nested route to be disable.

Comment: check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181539/why-angular2-routerlinkactive-sets-active-class-to-multiple-links)

Answer (score 9):

You have to define `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` to make the difference between `/productsList` and `/productsList/product`:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [routerLink]="['/productsList']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">not sad</a>
```